# How to manage R packages in spark cluster

Tags: r, hadoop, parallel-processing, apache-spark, sparkr

I´m working with a small spark cluster (5 DataNodes and 2 NameNodes) with version 1.3.1. I read this entry in a berkeley blog:

https://amplab.cs.berkeley.edu/large-scale-data-analysis-made-easier-with-sparkr/

Where it´s detailled how to implement gradient descent using sparkR; running a user-defined gradient function in parallel through the sparkR method "lapplyPartition". If lapplyPartition makes user-defined gradient function executed in every node, I guess that all the methods used inside the user-defined gradient function should be available in very node too. That means, R and all its packages should be installed in every node. Did I understood well?

If so, is there any way of managing the R packages? Now my cluster is small so we can do it manually, but I guess those people with large clusters won't do it like this. Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: _R and all its packages should be installed in every node._ - yes. _ Any suggestion?_ - there are multiple automation tools out there but recommendations are off-topic on SO.

Comment: lapplyPartition has been dropped from 1.4.  If this is a long term solution, you may be going down a dead end

Comment: @piccolbo Actually it has been moved to internal API. Not that it makes a big difference.

Comment: @zero323 It does make a difference: you can export internal API elements by altering the source code without having to write your own functions. I am not suggesting that this is the best solution however...

Comment: @zero323 exactly. They are as good as gone. Not supported. Bugs are not fixed anymore. Future is uncertain. ::: operator use triggers build warnings. Code against them at your own peril. You've been warned.

Comment: @Wannes-Rosiers, what you call "not the best" I call "dead end" or "trap". They are good for a one-liner that works between now and dinner time. We can agree on that.